Traduzione di un periodo ipotetico
Ciao a tutte/i. Oggi tra amici (tutti madrelingua italiani) siamo rimasti con un dubbio che fatichiamo a sciogliere.
Dovendo tradurre dall'inglese la frase "If you were having a problem, how likely is it that you would seek help?", ci siamo divisi tra due versioni:

Se avessi un problema, quanto è probabile che chiederesti aiuto?
Se avessi un problema, quanto sarebbe probabile che chiedessi aiuto?

Ad alcuni sembra grammaticalmente corretta la prima frase e scorretta la seconda, mentre altri sono convinti del contrario. O sono entrambe corrette ma con sfumature di significato diverse?
La frase poi è stata tradotta in un modo sicuramente più fluido ("Se avessi un problema, con che probabilità chiederesti aiuto?"), ma siamo rimasti col dubbio!
Grazie a chi ci aiuterà

Il “che” di solito richiede il congiuntivo…..

Ciao Pollinicchio, quando non trovo una spiegazione valida qui, chiedo aiuto in alcuni gruppi su Facebook, per esempio: LA LINGUA BATTE - Radio3, oppure: Lingua e Grammatica: regole, esempi, questioni e dubbi. In questo modo ho sempre risolto i miei dubbi. Prova a postare lì anche tu, se non hai voglia di farlo, posso farlo per te. Sono curiosa di sapere la risposta, fammi sapere.
